# How to run Playwright Inspector inside WSL2?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, playwright

I have Playwright running inside WSL2 on Windows 10. WSL is configured to work with GUI apps. Opening browsers is fine, but when starting with Playwright Inspector

`# npx playwright codegen google.de -b wk --viewport-size "1024,768"`

the inspector window remains empty, see right side of the screenshot below.

Again, Playwright itself works fine. It is only Inspector I have trouble with. How to get Playwright Inspector working in WSL2?

[image]

```
> wsl --version
WSL-Version: 1.0.3.0
Kernelversion: 5.15.79.1
WSLg-Version: 1.0.47
MSRDC-Version: 1.2.3575
Direct3D-Version: 1.606.4
DXCore-Version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows Version: 10.0.19044.2486
```

Answer (score 0):

WSL and Playwright work well:

[image: WSL and Playwright work well]

WSL: 1.2.5.0

Playwright Version 1.35.1

Run in docker:

```
docker run --rm -it -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix --env DISPLAY=:0 mcr.microsoft.com/playwright bash
```

And start the program:

```
npx playwright codegen --browser wk --viewport-size "1024,768" google.ru
```